# Css Scale Container but do not Scale the Inner Div Containing Text

Tags: css, transform

Here is a fiddle of my issue http://jsfiddle.net/887YU/97/.

I scale the outer div up and scale the inner div down.

```
.container:hover .box-back{
    /* at the same time flip the back side into visibility */
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg) scale3d(3,3,3);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    }

.box-back * {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.33,.33,.33);
}
```

This sort of works but the text in the inner div spacing is messed up and I'm not sure how to fix it. By that I mean the text starts at the bottom of the container when the container is moused over and flipped. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: updated my description a bit. I just want the text to start at the top on the back side of the card. If you mouse over the container you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `transform-origin: center top;` to your `.box-back *` rule

```
.box-back * {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.33,.33,.33);
    transform-origin: center top;
}
```